# Hosting interactive Bokeh plots independent of the Bokeh server

Tags: python, bokeh

I have created a Bokeh Document that currently hosts two plots. The first employs two widgets that control a barchart while the other is a standalone choropleth map. Using the Bokeh server, the plots are completely interactive and dropdown and button widgets are able to dynamically update the source data and sort barchart respectively, but I am trying to share this Document with colleagues that simply want to visualize these data in the same fashion on a web page independent of the Bokeh server.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want a standalone html document with embedded JS see Standalone Documents in https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html That will probably require to code some CustomJS callback functions in JS.